# Peewee How to regenerate a Select after it has been used?

Tags: python, peewee

In the Peewee ORM, When a `Select` object is iterated over, it becomes exhausted and cannot be used again:

```
query = Tweet.select()

list(query)  # This executes the SQL

list(query)  # This does not, but will return the same rows that are cached from the first query.
```

Calling `Select.iterator()` doesn't work. I think iterator will just prevent the results from being cached but it doesn't reset the cursor.

```
query = Tweet.select()

list(query.iterator())  # Executes SQL

list(query.iterator())  # This raises a pysopg2.InterfaceError: cursor already closed
```

Is it possible to regenerate a Select object so that it can be used again (and execute a subsequent SQL to the database), short of wrapping it in a function/duplicating the select statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `clone()` method:

```
query = User.select()
list(query)

query = query.clone()
list(query)  # New execution of query.
```

Comment: when using `query.iterator()` should it be `query.clone().iterator()` or `query.iterator().clone()` ?